# Upload of file taking long than download (HTTP POST)

Tags: java, http, tomcat, servlets, upload

I am uploading a file to a Servlet (Tomcat) using HTTP POST from Javascript client. And downloading using GET from the client. There is a vast difference in UL and DL times, from the same client. Cant figure out why, the difference when identical code is used

Servlet File I/O code for UPLOAD (read and save)

```
          String outputfile = this.getServletContext().getRealPath(FileName);  
          FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream (outputfile);            
          byte[] Ubuffer = new byte[4096];
          int bytesRead = -1;
          while ((bytesRead = is.read(Ubuffer)) != -1) {
            os.write(Ubuffer, 0, bytesRead);            
          }
          os.close();
```

Servlet File I/O code for DOWNLOAD (read and send

```
    OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead = -1;         
    while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);            
    }         
    inStream.close();
    outStream.close();
```

Appreciate some insights

Comment: Is your connection fully symmetrical?

Comment: Often upload speeds are significantly slower than download speeds from your internet service provider. Try using http://www.speedtest.net to find out what your rates are.  It might have nothing to do with your code or the server.

Comment: Thanks. It is not symmetric, but the upload is taking much longer than upload of the same file thru other applications. Is there an optimal buffer size for such I/O?